# Meaning of sentences with 続ける when paired with に

Tags: translation, meaning

Normally I see that 続ける is being paired with を instead, eg , 仕事を続けてください。(please continue working).

But what about this example i got after searching one of the many definitions of the て-form from kotobank.jp ([https://kotobank.jp/word/て-573101#E3.83.87.E3.82.B8.E3.82.BF.E3.83.AB.E5.A4.A7.E8.BE.9E.E6.B3.89](https://kotobank.jp/word/%E3%81%A6-573101#E3.83.87.E3.82.B8.E3.82.BF.E3.83.AB.E5.A4.A7.E8.BE.9E.E6.B3.89)).

**補助動詞に続けて**、動作・作用の内容を具体的に示す意を表す。
(補助動詞に続けて、action・represents the specific indication of the contents of an action.) , it means something like this right ? What does 補助動詞に続けて mean ?

Another example I got from the web is "飲み忘れずに続けるコツ", what does this mean ? Also, how does the verb 飲み忘れる come to exist as I cant find anything about it on the dictionary? Shouldn't it be a compound verb like 着替える or 繰り返す ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Depending on the context, ～に続ける means both of the following:

- to continue **from** ～; to follow ～ (～の後に続ける)

  > - 彼に続けて話す
  >     to speak following his speech
  > - メインディッシュに続けてデザートを食べる
  >     to eat dessert after the main dish
  > - 昨日に続けて今日もその仕事をしています。
- to continue **to** ～; to be followed by ～ (～へ続ける, ～へ続くようにする)

  > - 補助動詞に続けて
  >     continuing to a subsidiary verb
  > - 今回の成功を次の成功に続けたい。
  >     I want to make this success to be followed by next ones.
  > - 次ページに続ける to continue to the next page

Something like 攻撃を回避に続ける is ambiguous and can mean both "to dodge right after attacking" or "to attack right after dodging" depending on the context. In your case, it's obviously about the te-form followed by a subsidiary verb.

---

But に has many functions, and に right before 続ける may play different roles:

> - この仕事を彼に続けて欲しい。
>     I want him to continue this job. (彼に modifies 欲しい rather than 続ける)
> - 効果的に続けてトレーニングをする
>     to effectively continue the training (に turns a na-adjective to an adverb)
> - 飲み忘れずに続けてください。
>     Please continue (taking the pills) without forgetting to do so. (に is part of the [ずに construction](https://japanesetest4you.com/flashcard/learn-jlpt-n3-grammar-%E3%81%9A%E3%81%AB-zuni/))

Comment: Hmm , for に to mean "from", should'nt the verb have a nuance of "receiving" like for example "先生に習った" or "彼にもらう" ?

Comment: @Fishsticks Then you may want to understand it as "to connect to X" rather than "to continue from X".

Comment: Are there any more verbs that work like this ? If you dont mind naming a few and if anything comes to mind

Comment: @Fishsticks Not at the moment. Let's think the shared underlying meaning of ～に続ける is "to make it continuous with X", where X can be both something in the past and something in the future.

Answer (score 2):

> 補助動詞に続けて

It means "followed by `補助動詞`" when using the て-form.

Like the example shown on the website:

「思い出して`みる`」「嫌になって`しまう`」

> 飲み忘れずに続ける

This means, `Continue without forgetting to drink`.
And 飲み忘れる means `forgot to drink`. which is a composition of noun (飲み) and verb (忘れる).

Comment: I suggest making it clear that 飲み忘れずに and 続ける are referring to the same thing. When Japanese is translated to English, it often appears redundant, since redundancy is generally not liked in English, the reader assumes it is not redundant. So "continue without forgetting to drink" looks like two separate things "Continue (to exercise) without forgetting to drink (water)" but the Japanese is actually talking about the same thing,  "continue (to take your medicine) without forgetting to take your medicine" https://www.calpis-shop.jp/drink_check/ (I assume this is where the example came from)

Comment: I appreciate the reply but I still dont quite understand the use of に with 続ける、in the first example can i think of it as something like "followed by 補助動詞" and in the second example why not use を instead ?

Comment: @Fishsticks Yes definitely "followed by 補助動詞" makes more sense. I have edited my answers. 
And what do you mean by `を instead`? 
飲み忘れず**を**続ける is not correct.

Comment: Ah of course , 飲み忘れず is a verb so it cannot take the を particle ,silly me . Also, is it right for me to interpret the noun/verb that is marked by に to be like the "target" ? So for the first example it will be something like "continue/follow (with) 補助動詞" and for the second is "continue to drink without forgetting".

Comment: Yup, you're right.